# Possible to monitor LAN traffic (who is visiting what urls and for how long)

Tags: networking, monitoring, network-monitoring

I am attempting to limit my children's internet/video viewing am aware of some paid options but for starters I am try to get an idea of what they are watching and for how long (I have  my own biased observations but prefer something more definitive). If I can see something as granular as full URLs and how long they are being viewed that would be awesome but I am not sure its possible.

I have a dd-wrt flashed router if that helps? I am hoping to do it at the network level as they use various devices (iphone, mac, pc)

Comment: Are you on Windows? If yes, see [Microsoft Family Safety](https://www.microsoft.com/en/microsoft-365/family-safety?market=af).

Comment: @harrymc he clearly wrote "iphone, mac, pc"

Comment: @YisroelTech: There is no one solution good for all devices, even DD-WRT monitoring can be avoided via VPN. Microsoft Family Safety may solve some of his problem.

Comment: That might be correct (though there are cross platform parental control options out there), I just responded to your question if he's on Windows, which he has answered in his question.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback so far. Fortunately my kids arent at the point of figuring out VPNs. They switch between a mac, iphones, and a PC so that was the main reason I was hoping for something that could track at the LAN level rather than per device (though this might not be possible). For actual blocking i think Disney has the most comprehensive/granular product but I was hoping to first be able to see more clearly what is being watched (though I think I know) and more importantly how long each of these things (mostly ytube) are being watched.